# Load Url in Web View

Tags: android

I have a small problem that I want to load a url in web view but it doesn't displayed in webview, it displayed in default Android browser. How can we resist this to open in webview and one thing more that if I will use any other web url then it simply displayed in web view. This problem with only my particular url. What is the solution for that.

My url: http://www.bizrate.com/rd?t=http%3A%2F%2Fclickfrom.buy.com%2Fdefault.asp%3Fadid%3D17865%26sURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2F4x-silicone-skin-soft-gel-case-for-htc-droid-incredible%2Fq%2Floc%2F111%2F219945395.html&mid=18893&cat_id=8515&atom=8517&prod_id=2513751439&oid=2388674793&pos=1&b_id=18&bid_type=4&bamt=45e4b920dcffc474&rf=af1&af_assettype_id=10&af_creative_id=6&af_id=50087&af_placement_id=1

my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.storesite);

    //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_store);
    //MyWebViewClient web1 = new MyWebViewClient();
    //web1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(web, "http://www.bizrate.com/rd?t=http%3A%2F%2Fclickfrom.buy.com%2Fdefault.asp%3Fadid%3D17865%26sURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2F4x-silicone-skin-soft-gel-case-for-htc-droid-incredible%2Fq%2Floc%2F111%2F219945395.html&mid=18893&cat_id=8515&atom=8517&prod_id=2513751439&oid=2388674793&pos=1&b_id=18&bid_type=4&bamt=45e4b920dcffc474&rf=af1&af_assettype_id=10&af_creative_id=6&af_id=50087&af_placement_id=1");
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.bizrate.com/rd?t=http%3A%2F%2Fclickfrom.buy.com%2Fdefault.asp%3Fadid%3D17865%26sURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2F4x-silicone-skin-soft-gel-case-for-htc-droid-incredible%2Fq%2Floc%2F111%2F219945395.html&mid=18893&cat_id=8515&atom=8517&prod_id=2513751439&oid=2388674793&pos=1&b_id=18&bid_type=4&bamt=45e4b920dcffc474&rf=af1&af_assettype_id=10&af_creative_id=6&af_id=50087&af_placement_id=1");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
 web.loadUrl("http://www.bizrate.com/rd?t=http%3A%2F%2Fclickfrom.buy.com%2Fdefault.asp%3Fadid%3D17865%26sURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2F4x-silicone-skin-soft-gel-case-for-htc-droid-incredible%2Fq%2Floc%2F111%2F219945395.html&mid=18893&cat_id=8515&atom=8517&prod_id=2513751439&oid=2388674793&pos=1&b_id=18&bid_type=4&bamt=45e4b920dcffc474&rf=af1&af_assettype_id=10&af_creative_id=6&af_id=50087&af_placement_id=1");


    public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: this nothing affect, problem remains same. Url open in default Android Browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // get the web view
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // prepare the web view
    registerForContextMenu(webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new ItemWebViewClient());
  }

  private class ItemWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      // show progress bar

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      // hide the progress bar

    }
  }
```